# try and ignore errors in my tcl command

Tags: error-handling, try-catch, tcl

Hi I am new to tcl and I am trying to run a command in a for loop, while this command does what it needs to do, but, it throws an exception, which causes the loop to break. So, I need to ignore any error that is produced by this command and still try the command each time in my for loop.

```
for loop {
    #do some stuff
    $chassis exportPacketTrace $new_name -compress false 1 2 both #try this but ignore its error and continue
    #do some stuff
}
```

Please help me with a good solution for this problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if {[catch {$chassis exportPacketTrace $new_name -compress false 1 2 both} issue]} {
    puts "There is a failure and it is ignored"
    puts "Reason for failure : $issue"
}
```

**Reference :** [catch](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/catch.htm)

Comment: I have already figured it out. Yes, using 'catch' does the trick. +1 from me.